# Firebase Cloud Messaging + FirebaseInitProvider.zza(Unknown Source) on signed build

Tags: java, android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have integrated Firebase Cloud Messaging in my Android app by following steps provided at this link:

[Set Up a Firebase Cloud Messaging Client App on Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client)

Below is part of my app build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:11.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.1'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Below is my Project build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I am using AndroidStudio version 2.3.3

For some reasons when I install my app directly through AndroidStudio on device it works fine but when I create a signed build, install it and launch the same it crashes with below stack trace:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 Process: xyz.myapp, PID: 8723
 java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method zzb(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object; in class Lcom/google/android/gms/common/internal/zzac; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzac' appears in /data/app/xyz.myapp-1/base.apk)
     at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.zza(Unknown Source)
     at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown Source)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5852)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:5444)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5383)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap2(ActivityThread.java)
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1541)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6123)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:757)
```

I tried solutions proposed at this link: [Firebase API initialization failure. (java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError) #24](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/issues/24) but none worked for me :(

Am I missing anything over here?

Comment: Sounds like you missed some proguard settings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens when you are using multiple Firebase (or Google Play services) libraries **with different versions between each other.**

Firebase (and Google Play services) libraries **MUST be all at the same version.**

It's possible that this issue is not introduced by you but by some other library that is depending on a specific version of same library.

Run `./gradlew dependencies` to check the list of dependencies and their version.

**UPDATE**: if the dependencies look ok, but the problem persist, try `./gradlew clean` & rebuild.