# App won't start on Google Repository 55 with any firebase-messaging version

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

When I start up my application, it will immediately crash before the main activity starts with the following stack trace:

```
ca.uwaterloo.foodwithfriends E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Process: ca.uwaterloo.foodwithfriends, PID: 20134

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method zzcL(Ljava/lang/String;)Z in 
    class Lcom/google/android/gms/common/util/zzt; or its super classes 
(declaration of 'com.google.android.gms.common.util.zzt' appears in /data/app/ca.uwaterloo.foodwithfriends-1/base.apk)
at com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions.fromResource(Unknown Source)
at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source)
at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(Unknown Source)
at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1748)
at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1723)
at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown Source)
at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5262)
at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4847)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4787)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1452)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:234)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5526)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method).java:726)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

This stack trace started appearing after I upgraded my firebase libraries in my build.gradle file to 11.0.2 due to an issue receiving messages. This required an update to Google Repository 55. Since then reverting to previous versions of firebase-messaging and google play services has been ineffective, including reverting to the exact same revision but with Google Repository 55 as was starting but not receiving messages earlier today.

The following code block is my build.gradle file for my app trying to run the current versions of firebase and of google play services.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "ca.uwaterloo.foodwithfriends"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

defaultConfig {
    jackOptions {
        enabled true
    }
}
dexOptions {

}

compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
}

repositories {
mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile files('libs/foodwithfriends-common.jar')


androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', 
{
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:11.0.2'
compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.0.0-RC0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
compile 'com.github.pwittchen:infinitescroll:0.0.1'
compile 'com.github.clans:fab:1.6.4'
compile 'com.stripe:stripe-android:4.1.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.2'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19'
testCompile 'com.google.dexmaker:dexmaker-mockito:1.1'
androidTestCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19'
androidTestCompile 'com.google.dexmaker:dexmaker-mockito:1.1'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.0.0-RC0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

This block is of the project build.gradle file.

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to 
all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

The working setup earlier today was Google Repository 54, with google play services in project at 3, google play services at app as 10.2.6, and firebase at version 10.0.1. Google Repository 55 with google play services in project at 3, google play services at app as 10.2.6, and firebase at version 10.0.1 does not work. I updated due to the receiving messages issue which I read could be because of non compatible versions between all these dependencies.

edit - Possible duplicate question had an answer that there are incompatible dependencies that may be exposed by running `gradlew dependencies`. I did this and the result did not seem to include a different version for any google-play-services or firebase dependency. See below:

```
+--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1
|    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.3.1
|    +--- com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.3.1
|    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.3.1
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-media-compat:25.3.1
|    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.3.1
|    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.3.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:25.3.1
|    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.3.1
|    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.3.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:25.3.1
|    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.3.1
|    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.3.1 (*)
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-fragment:25.3.1
|    |         +--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.3.1 (*)
|    |         +--- com.android.support:support-media-compat:25.3.1 (*)
|    |         +--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:25.3.1 (*)
|    |         \--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:25.3.1 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:25.3.1
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.3.1
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.3.1 (*)
|    \--- com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:25.3.1
|         \--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:25.3.1 (*)
+--- com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2
|    \--- com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout-solver:1.0.2
+--- com.android.support:design:25.3.1
|    +--- com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.3.1
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.3.1 (*)
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:25.3.1 (*)
|    \--- com.android.support:transition:25.3.1
|         +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.3.1
|         \--- com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1 (*)
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.2
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:[11.0.2] -> 11.0.2
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[11.0.2] -> 11.0.2
|    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:25.2.0 -> 25.3.1 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:[11.0.2] -> 11.0.2
|    |         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[11.0.2] -> 11.0.2 (*)
|    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[11.0.2] -> 11.0.2 (*)
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.2
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:[11.0.2] -> 11.0.2 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[11.0.2] -> 11.0.2 (*)
|    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:[11.0.2] -> 11.0.2 (*)
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:11.0.2
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:[11.0.2] -> 11.0.2 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[11.0.2] -> 11.0.2 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:[11.0.2] -> 11.0.2 (*)
|    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:[11.0.2] -> 11.0.2 (*)
+--- com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0
+--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7
+--- com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5) -> 4.24.0
|    +--- com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.3.1
|    +--- com.android.support:customtabs:25.3.1
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.3.1 (*)
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.3.1
|    \--- com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.4.0
|         +--- com.parse.bolts:bolts-tasks:1.4.0
|         \--- com.parse.bolts:bolts-applinks:1.4.0
|              \--- com.parse.bolts:bolts-tasks:1.4.0
+--- com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.0.0-RC0
|    +--- com.github.bumptech.glide:gifdecoder:4.0.0-RC0
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.3.1
|    +--- com.github.bumptech.glide:disklrucache:4.0.0-RC0
|    \--- com.github.bumptech.glide:annotations:4.0.0-RC0
+--- com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1 (*)
+--- de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0
+--- com.github.pwittchen:infinitescroll:0.0.1
|    \--- com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1 -> 25.3.1 (*)
+--- com.github.clans:fab:1.6.4
+--- com.stripe:stripe-android:4.1.1
|    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.3.1
|    +--- com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1 (*)
|    \--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1 (*)
+--- com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.2
|    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:[11.0.2] -> 11.0.2
|         +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:[11.0.2] -> 11.0.2
|         |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[11.0.2] -> 11.0.2 (*)
|         |    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:[11.0.2] -> 11.0.2
|         |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[11.0.2] -> 11.0.2 (*)
|         |    |    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:[11.0.2] -> 11.0.2
|         |    |         +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[11.0.2] -> 11.0.2 (*)
|         |    |         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:[11.0.2] -> 11.0.2 (*)
|         |    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:[11.0.2] -> 11.0.2 (*)
|         |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:[11.0.2] -> 11.0.2 (*)
|         +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[11.0.2] -> 11.0.2 (*)
|         \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:[11.0.2] -> 11.0.2 (*)
\--- com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.2
     +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:[11.0.2] -> 11.0.2 (*)
     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[11.0.2] -> 11.0.2 (*)
     \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:[11.0.2] -> 11.0.2 (*)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firebase Cloud Messaging + FirebaseInitProvider.zza(Unknown Source) on signed build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44739829/firebase-cloud-messaging-firebaseinitprovider-zzaunknown-source-on-signed-bu)

Comment: @DiegoGiorgini I checked that question, thanks for the link, and ran the dependencies task to check if I had any incompatible libraries. I edited the main question to include my dependencies output. I don't see anything that doesn't match 11.0.2

Comment: thank you. your case is strange. could you try running "./gradlew clean" and build again ? if it doesn't work, can you try to disable proguard ?

Comment: gradle clean fixed it up! Care to throw it up as an answer so I can mark it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can happen when you have Firebase (or Google Play) deps   **using different versions**.

Run `./gradlew dependencies` to check the full list of dependencies.

If the dependencies are OK, but the problem persists, try `./gradlew clean` and build again.

Gradle could be using some cached code, and not the declared list of deps.